# Is traditional spanish music scale also Harmonic Minor Mixolydian scale?

Tags: theory, scales

Is it actually Harmonic Minor Mixolydian scale or is it called just "Spanish scale"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to the 5th mode of the harmonic minor scale, that scale is typically referred to as the *Phrygian Dominant* scale due to it being the Phrygian scale with one alteration that makes the tonic chord a dominant 7th. It does have other names one which is "Spanish Phrygian".

Built off of A, it would contain the following notes:

```
A B♭ C♯ D E F G
```